# Kotlinx.Serialization using OkHTTPClient return always Failure

Tags: json, kotlin, json-deserialization, kotlinx.serialization

Hello I have a problem with my JSON. I am using OkHTTPClient to get JSON from web - to get objects from JSON using kotlinx.serialization via method which contains this and return value from method should be Result :

```
private suspend inline fun <reified T> OkHttpClient.get(webUrl: HttpUrl): Result<T> =
    try {
        //Builder defined here ... but skipping this line of code
        val data = Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true }.decodeFromString<T (result.body!!.string())
        Result.Success(data)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Result.Failure(e)
    }


 suspend fun getFact(): Result<Fact> =
        client.httpGet("myURL".toHttpUrl())
```

Json from myURL:

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"fact":"This is random information i need to get"}],"message":"Retrieved Fact"}
```

My serializer and Serializable data classes:

```
@Serializable
data class Fact(
@Serializable(with = FactListSerializer::class)
val data: String) java.io.Serializable

object FactListSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<List<String>>(ListSerializer(String.serializer())) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        return if (element  is JsonArray) {
            JsonArray(listOf(element)).first()
        } else {
            element
        }
    }
}
```

To be honest I am not sure what I am doing, but I am getting this error all the time when I print val fact = api.getFact():

```
 Fact: Failure(error=kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected JsonPrimitive at 0, found {"fact":"This is random information i need to get"}
```

What I need to return is only first element of array fact, because JSON obtain always only 1 fact inside array. So I don't want to return from Serializer/Json List but only Fact object.
But as you see I am obtaining always Result Fauilure, don't know why. My goal is to obtain Result Success and obtaining from that JSON object Fact (only one), but I am not sure if I am doing it correct (obviously not) and even if it is even possible to return from JSONArray only one object (element of type Fact).

So what I expect is something like this:

```
Fact: Success(value=Fact(fact=This is random information i need to get))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the deserializer definition should be changed on 3 levels. The example of how to use `JsonTransformingDeserializer` [in the docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/-json-transforming-serializer/index.html) actually describes most of what you need.

1. `JsonArray(listOf(element)).first()` should just be `element.first()`. Here you're building a `JsonArray` containing your initial `JsonArray` as only element, and then taking the first, so you basically get back the exact same element.
2. The type parameter `T` of `JsonTransformingSerializer` is supposed to be the type of the property it's applied to, so you should at least get a warning in the code because yours is defined to work on `List<String>` but is applied to a `String` property. It should be `JsonTransformingSerializer<String>(String.serializer())`.
3. You not only need to unwrap the `data` array, you also need to extract the value of the `fact` key within the element of that array.

So with all these changes, it should give something like this:

```kotlin
object FactListSerializer : JsonTransformingSerializer<String>(String.serializer()) {
    override fun transformDeserialize(element: JsonElement): JsonElement {
        val unwrappedData = if (element is JsonArray) element.first() else element
        return unwrappedData.jsonObject["fact"] ?: error("missing 'fact' key in 'data' array")
    }
}
```

Comment: Works as expected, thank you very much + thanks for explanation what was wrong/what I need to do.